# Get Coordinates of duplicated numbers in matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need ideas, this is not a homework .......

I have the following matrix, how i can obtain the coordinates of duplicates numbers,

[image: imagen]

duplicates [ [ [0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,2],[1,3],[2,2] ], [ [0,3], [0,4] , ........ ]

momentary code:

```
n = [ [1,1,1,3,3],[1,2,1,1,2],[1,2,1,3,3] ]

coordinates = [[-1,0],[0,1],[1,0],[0,-1]]
i = 0
while i < len(n):
    j = 0
    fila = []
    while j < len(n[0]):
        for coordinate in coordinates:
            X = i + coordinate[0]
            Y = j + coordinate[1]
            if X >= 0 and X < len(n) and Y >= 0 and Y < len(n[0]):
                # I tried with two for in here but its not efficient
        j+=1
    i+=1
```

Thanks

EDIT:

expected output:

Groups 1, separated 2, separated 3 and only 2

duplicates [ [ [0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,2],[1,3],[2,2] ], [ [0,3], [0,4] ], [ [1,1],[2,1] ] , [ [1,4] ], [ [2,3], [2,4] ]

Comment: Your drawing seems to indicate that spatially unconnected values belong to the same group, but your code does not because you are using a structuring element whereby you check for neighboring connectivity (with a square connectivity equal to one, in other words "a plus-type" of connectivity). What is your expected output from the array you have given as `n`?

Comment: Is the range of values in the matrix limited? If not, what is the range? Also, what about all those `1`s, aren't they duplicates, too?

Comment: @martineau max matrix 10 x 10

Comment: @PM2Ring I edited this, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not extremely efficient, as the test array is used in a logical comparison check multiple times, but most loops are pushed to the C-level.
At the same time, it demonstrates a few interesting methods you could explore if you have similar functionality to perform.

```
import scipy.ndimage as nd    
import numpy as np

n = np.array([ [1,1,1,3,3],[1,2,1,1,2],[1,2,1,3,3] ], dtype=np.int)

def print_coord(val, pos, shape):
    print("{}: {}".format(val[0], list(zip(*np.unravel_index(pos, dims=shape)))))
    return 0

for val in np.unique(n):
    labelled_array, num_features = nd.label(n == val)
    nd.labeled_comprehension(n, labelled_array, [1,2,3], 
        lambda v, p: print_coord(v, p, shape=n.shape), float, 0, True)
```

Output:

```
1: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
2: [(1, 1), (2, 1)]
2: [(1, 4)]
3: [(0, 3), (0, 4)]
3: [(2, 3), (2, 4)]
```

You could of course append the results to a list, when you are not interested in keeping the label that matched that list of coordinates.

Comment: Thanks you very much

Answer (score 1):

According to an output you provided to your example, I came up with the following solution:

```
import sys

def findMax(n, m, mat):
    max = -sys.maxint - 1
    for i in xrange(n):
        for j in xrange(m):
            if mat[i][j] > max:
                max = mat[i][j]
    return max


def doIt(mat):
    n, m = len(mat), len(mat[0])
    max_val = findMax(n, m, mat)
    memo = [None] * (max_val + 1)
    for i in xrange(n):
        for j in xrange(m):
            if memo[mat[i][j]] is None:
                memo[mat[i][j]] = [(i, j)]
            else:
                memo[mat[i][j]].append((i, j))
    return {i: item for i, item in enumerate(memo) if item is not None and len(item) > 1}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = [ [1,1,1,3,3],[1,2,1,1,2],[1,2,1,3,3] ]
    print doIt(n)
```

`memo` is a list where index indicate a potential duplicate number and corresponding value is the list of coordinates. Originally `memo` is initialized with `None` of length `max` found by traversing input matrix (O(N^2)). Key observation - If there are more than one pair of coordinates for specific number in `memo`, then we found a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non-Numpy solution. It uses [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to separate the coordinates into lists that have the that share the same value in `n`, then it separate those into sublists consisting of neighbours.

```
from itertools import product, groupby

n = [
    [1, 1, 1, 3, 3],
    [1, 2, 1, 1, 2],
    [1, 2, 1, 3, 3],
]

# Return a value from `n` given a coordinate tuple
def keyfunc(t):
    y, x = t
    return n[y][x]

# Make a list of coordinate tuples. 
# This code assumes that all rows in `n` have the same length
a = list(product(range(len(n)), range(len(n[0]))))

# Sort coordinates by the corresponding value in `n`
a.sort(key=keyfunc)

#Split the sorted coordinates into lists that share the same value...
groups = []
for k, g in groupby(a, key=keyfunc):
    # ... and separate those into sublists consisting of neighbours
    # We must turn g into a proper list
    sublists = []
    for t in list(g):
        y, x = t
        neighbours = [(y-1, x), (y+1, x), (y, x-1), (y, x+1)]
        # Search for a sublist that contains a neighbour of `t`
        for lst in sublists:
            if any(u in lst for u in neighbours):
                lst.append(t)
                break
        else:
            # No sublist of neighbours found, start a new one
            sublists.append([t])
    groups.append((k, sublists))

for row in groups:
    print(row)
```

**output**

```
(1, [[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 0), (2, 2)]])
(2, [[(1, 1), (2, 1)], [(1, 4)]])
(3, [[(0, 3), (0, 4)], [(2, 3), (2, 4)]])
```